# Finding the row of an object

Tags: math, geometry, vertex

I'm trying to create a procedural shape made up of quads.

I want to be able to take any quad and use it's index to find the row that it is in.

Take quad 9 from the image. What sort of function can I use to find the row (in this case it is 2 from a 0-index). What about quad 20?

The rows always change in width by 2 quads, one removed from each side.

Sorry it's a bit convoluted but I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

[image: QuadDiagram]

Comment: How do we know how many quads in each row? Or is there some diagram each time? What is the internal representation you have chosen? For instance I can imagine summing just until the number of quads in the current row would take you over the index (or mabe equal, requires thought), but that presumes you have an array with the number of quads in each row.

Comment: Well the shape is defined by the diameter (our input) which is always a multiple of two (4, 6, 8, 10) so that it mirrors across the X and Y axis without sharing quads. Since we remove two quads for each step we can get the number of quads in a row by subtracting two times the distance to the center. So in the example image we can look at the second row from the top. The distance to the center =  (diameter/2) - row and   numOfQuadsinRow = diameter - (distance * 2) =. So the second row has a distance of 1, 6 - (1 * 2) = 4.

Comment: So n your 0 index scheme, the nth row, until the middle, starts with n(n+1) and ends with (n+1)(n+2)-1. It feels like given a quad number up to the middle, you could solve the quadratic equation n^2+n-quad=0 and truncate the answer. (Also take the plus sqrt in the quadratic formula). Still to flesh out is how you know where the middle is, indexwise, and how to use symmetry to reduce a case beyond the middle to one before it.

Comment: So like trunc ((-1+sqrt(1+4*quad))/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume diameter d and quad number q. I claim the rows go 0 to d-1. Moreover, there are (d/2)(2+d) elements. The easier case is if 0<=q<(d/4)(2+d) in which case we are in the first half. Then the index is trunc((-1+sqrt(1+4*q))/2). This comes from using the observation that row n begins with n(n+1) which could be formally shown with the sum of an arithmetic series, then working backwards and solving the quadratic equation.
On the other hand, if we are in the second half (d/4)(2+d)<=q<(d/2)(2*d) and we solve by taking the offset from the end. Let q' be (d/2)(2+d)-1-q. Apply the above index formula to q' instead of q, and subtract the result from d-1 to get the index of q's row.
I may be off by one here or there, but I think this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking since this was posted to a programming site, maybe it would be more logical to give a function one could implement without pulling out a lot of math, and instead just relying on addition. I think it would be easier to follow and harder to mess up (though maybe I underestimate my capability to mess up, and I almost did).

```js
var quadRowIndex = function (diameter, quadNumber) {
//diameter should be a positive even number
//quadNumber should be between 0 and index of last number in last row (inclusive)
var quadIndex = 0; //holds the RowIndex, which the function will return once the row contains quadNumber
var rowStartNum = 0;
var rowLength = 2;

//iterate through first half
while (rowLength <= diameter) {
    rowStartNum += rowLength;
    if (rowStartNum > quadNumber) {
        return quadIndex;
    }
    quadIndex++;
    rowLength += 2;
}
rowLength -= 2;
//iterate through second half if still here
while (rowLength >= 2) {
    rowStartNum += rowLength;
    if (rowStartNum > quadNumber) {
        return quadIndex;
    }
    quadIndex++;
    rowLength -= 2;
}
//still here -- number was too high, return error signal
return -1;
};
console.log(quadRowIndex(6, 9));
console.log(quadRowIndex(6, 20));
console.log(quadRowIndex(6, 100));
```